# I want to Send data to relaychain from parachain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot-js, polkadot, xcm, polkadot-sdk

I want to send JSON or normal String Message from Parachain to relay chain but i new in the substrate and I am finding it difficult.
I am using the Polkadot-sdk template for relaychain and substrate-parachain-template for parachain. Both are connected but I don't how to transfer data using XCM.